# Why remove recursively only removes in directly I'm in?

Tags: linux, wordpress, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to clean up my WP uploads folder, getting rid of all the resized images I don't use.

I run:

```
    rm -rf *-100x100.* *-1024x576.* *-1080x608.* *-1080x675.* *-1280x640.
    * *-1280x720.* *-150x150.* *-150x84.* *-250x141.* *-26x26.* *-300x169.* *-400x250.* 
    *-400x284.* *-400x516.* *-440x264.* *-440x440.* *-627x376.* *-64x64.* *-768x432.*
```

and it removes the expected files from the directory I am in... but not the subdirectories. Shouldn't -rf work recursively and go into those directories and remove those files?

What can I do to accomplish this?

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.7.  (and yes, I tried the Force Regenerate Thumbnails plugin to delete these files, that didn't work either (could that be related to the problem I'm having with rm - rf?))

Appreciate any thoughts on this!

Comment: wildcards are being expendad by the shell rm only receives a list of files,  verify by echo *-100x100, you want to generate a list of all files grep the matching and then delete, also some shells (zsh) have an options of globbing from sub folders.

Comment: You're better off using `find`. Something like `find . \( -name "*-100x100.*" -o -name "*-1024.576.*" ... \) -delete`